# Is there any way i can run my react project on my phone within same network

Tags: reactjs

I want to see my react app on my phone whcich is running on localhost:3000, is there any way i can run the app on my phone...?
I am using vite to initiate the app.

I tried connecting with same network and run it on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to expose the react app to your network as shown below.

To run your react app on mobile you need to know your IP address. (Assuming you are on the same network).
To know your devices IP address use `ifconfig` or `ip addr` for linux
and `ipconfig` for windows

Now in your phone enter the IP address in web browser along with the port on which react app is running.

`http://yourIPaddress:port`

Example
`http://192.168.XX.XX:3000`

In the package.json file under scripts add --host as shown below

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
}
```

This is will expose the react app to your network and you can connect to it.